# PLSQL with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have quite a few lines of PL/SQL code in Oracle 10g, and we are going to move to 11g. I expect my code to work there too, but:

- Are there any pitfalls to expect, any problems you encountered?
- What new features are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big new feature for me is the [PL/SQL Function Result Cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/subprograms.htm#BABFHACJ), for functions that you call over and over again.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/whatsnew.htm#CJAEGHHH for the complete PL/SQL "What's New". DBMS_PARALLEL_UPDATE looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm certainly going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

We recently upgraded to 11g and had no issues with our previous stored procs.  It was a pretty smooth upgrade for us.  As is always recommended, upgrade a test environment and do testing of your SPs and database dependent apps to ensure your environment doesn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

So far my only issue with 11.1 is that Natively Compiled PL/SQL is running 2-3% slower than Interpreted. Was quite a surprise for us. Supposedly things are working better in 11.2 but haven't had time to mess with it yet.